# Does a MongoDB cursor "auto-grow" when I add documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using a MongoDB cursor to find a large number of documents, which takes quite some time. What happens if during this time, there are documents added to the database that match the search criteria of the cursor.

Will the cursor return the documents?
Or does the cursor take some kind of snapshot if it begins, and thus omits the later added results?

Answer (score 1):

> Will the cursor return the documents?

Yes. This also happens when you update some documents which you received from the cursor, causing them to grow out of their current disk bounds and move to a bigger slot in the data files. In this case, you may see such documents twice (or more).

Comment: This happened to me a few times (with the MMAPv1 engine). Was quite a surprise every time :) Not sure how WT handles this, but I would assume it behaves similarly. @NeilLunn?

Comment: Thanks! What if I have a cursor-query on "updated_at > xx:yy:zz", and a script alters the updated_at of a document that has already been returned. Will it be returned a second time?

Comment: I have asked this second question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50745688/can-a-mongodb-cursor-return-an-altered-document-twice