# Can a MongoDB cursor return an altered document twice?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB cursor-query on "updated_at > xx:yy:zz". Another script X can alter the updated_at of documents.

What if the 'updated_at' of a document is updated by script X after it has been returned by the cursor, wil it be returned a second time by the cursor?

Comment: Sure, but not because of the value of the field, but because of the move of the document. Use [snapshot](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/method/cursor.snapshot/) if you can.

Comment: Please don't re-post questions. If you have additional content to add to an existing question then you can do that. But asking the same thing again is not a practice to continue. If you don't like someones answer, then tell them what you think is not addressed in what you are asking, or ask them for clarification on what you believed was missed. You can always edit the question to raise more attention, or add a bounty. Other people of course can still add answers.

Comment: @NeilLunn the questions are different. My first question was about when new documents are added, this question’s is when existing documents are altered. Two different questions with two different answers. A duplicate question would result in the same set of answers.

Comment: I don't see any difference. *"... if during this time, there are documents added to the database ..."* and *"..What if the 'updated_at' of a document is updated by script X ..."* is asking the same thing. It certainly has the same answer anyway. See [Read Isolation, Consistency, and Recency](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/)

Comment: It all depends on how the cursor works. New documents and updated documents can make a huge difference. Anyway, if you know the answer, please be so kind to answer it :)

Comment: @Pim: looksl like the linked article explains it: "or that change the indexed field on the index used by the query; then the cursor will return the same document more than once"